# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm following a javascript/coffeescript/canvas tutorial, I have this javascript code:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var canvas, context;
    console.log("DOM is ready");
    canvas = $('#myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.font = '40pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    return context.fillText('Hello World!', 150, 100);
  });

}).call(this);
```

on calling `canvas.getContext()`, I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.`

If I replace `canvas = $('#myCanvas');` with `document.getElementById('myCanvas');` it works fine.

What do you think is the problem? Thank you!!

For info, this is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And my original Coffeescript:

```
$ ->
    console.log("DOM is ready")
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.font = '40pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.fillText('Hello World!', 150, 100);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that $('#myCanvas') returns jQuery object and document.getElementById('myCanvas') returns canvas html element. To get canvas context you need the element not an object. If you want use jQuery just change "canvas = $('#myCanvas');" to "canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];"